# Prove that natural density of $S_{\alpha} = \{\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is $\frac{1}{\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that natural density of $S_{\alpha} = \{\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is $\frac{1}{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is irrational real number. Here's my steps this far. 
According to the definition, $$d(A) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{|A \cap [1,N]|}{N}.$$ Then since $A = \{\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, we have $$d(A) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{|\{\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cap [1,N]|}{N}.$$ We let $\lfloor n\alpha \rfloor = k$. Then according to the definition of floor function, we have $\frac{k}{\alpha} < n < \frac{k+1}{\alpha}$. And also we have that $k = n\alpha - f$, with $f \in [0,1)$. Then we have $-\frac{k}{\alpha} = \frac{f}{\alpha} - n$. Then $\{-\frac{k}{\alpha}\} = \frac{f}{\alpha}$. Then since $f$ is an arbitrary element in $[0,1)$, then in order for $k \in A$, $\{\frac{-k}{\alpha}\} < \frac{1}{\alpha}$. Then I'm not sure what I need to do next. Could anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: We must assume $\alpha\ge1$.

Comment: @Lucenaposition Thanks for your comment! I ignored the range of natural density should be $\in [0,1)$

Comment: Actually, the range of natural density is $[0,1]$ not $[0,1)$ and the natural density is $1$ when $\alpha=1$.

Comment: @Lucenaposition Got it! Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question only makes sense for when $\alpha > 1$, because otherwise the density is 1.

Your are basically asking to compute cardinality bounds on $\{ \lfloor n \alpha\rfloor : n \in \{1,2,...\}\} \cap \{1,2,...,N\}$ where $N$ is fixed. Instead of looking at $\lfloor n\alpha\rfloor$, I'd look at $k = \lfloor N/\alpha \rfloor$.

Note that $$\alpha k \leq N < \alpha(k+1).$$
Since $\alpha > 1$, each of the $\alpha, 2\alpha,...,k\alpha$ are truncated to different natural numbers, so
$$\bigg|\{ \lfloor n \alpha\rfloor : n \in \{1,2,...\}\} \cap \{1,2,...,N\}\bigg| \geq k.$$
Likewise, we know that $\alpha(k+1)$ could get truncated to $N$ and be in our above set, but not $\alpha(k+2)$. Therefore,
$$\bigg|\{ \lfloor n \alpha\rfloor : n \in \{1,2,...\}\} \cap \{1,2,...,N\}\bigg| \leq k+1.$$

Thus, for each $N$,
our density $d(S_\alpha)$ falls in the interval
$$\left[ \frac{\lfloor N/\alpha\rfloor}{N},\frac{\lfloor N/\alpha\rfloor+1}{N}\right].$$
As you take $N \to \infty$, it's clear that this limit should converge to $1/\alpha$.